# Index of notifications list in notification center iOS

Tags: ios, push-notification

Can I get which push notification is clicked in Notification Center, I mean index of notification in list in app delegate.

Comment: add your language Tag for e.g, objective C or Siwft

Comment: better you get the one key in payload for index from your backend

Comment: from front end i need

Comment: better you get the one key in payload for index from your backend, if you press / receive the payload you easily know the index based on that key ,

Comment: Just to clarify: do you want to known which of **your** notifications is acted on by the user, or the position of the notification the user acted on in the list? If the former, follow @Anbu.Karthik's suggestion. If the latter, I don't think that information is available.

Comment: Yes,the index of notification which user clicked

Comment: Can we detect which notification has clicked in notification cenetr